# Dependency cycle upgrading to 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, upgrade

I've got the following error while attempting to upgrade from 8.04 to v 10.04. Is there anything I can do to resolve the issue?

> Upgrading Ubuntu to version 10.04 LTS
>   Could not install the upgrades Error
>   during commit 
> 'E:Couldn't configure
>   pre-depend jre for
>   openoffice.org-writer2latex, probably
>   a dependency cycle.' 
> Restoring
>   original system state

Comment: Try installing a JRE (e.g., `apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`), possibly the one from the 10.04 repo, _before_ trying the full upgrade. Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
apt-get remove openoffice.org-writer2latex
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install openoffice.org-writer2latex
```

Comment: thanks, I've uninstalled openoffice.org and the upgrade is now in progress

Comment: @Mark any update?

Comment: yes, the update worked after uninstalling open-office.