# Upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10 says it's still a Development Release?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 - now that Ubuntu 10.10 is finally released. I used `update-manager -d` and the first window after pressing the upgrade button says that it is still a development release.

Is this true? Or have they not changed this window yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`update-manager -d` *is* the command to upgrade to development trunk versions of Ubuntu.

However, I *think* I recall Ubuntu updates the repositories to notify about the new release a few days after the release is live so that when people are prompted to upgrade, the bandwidth use spike from the day 1 enthusiasts has been fully absorbed. By using that route, you should still end up with a copy of "blessed" Ubuntu 10.10.

That said, even if it *was* marked as a development version, [it wouldn't be any different.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5257/is-there-a-rational-reason-to-wait-for-the-release-date-to-download-install-or-u) Go ahead, make your day!

Comment: I tried to upgrade but I got a an error: 
'E:Couldn't configure pre-depend x11-common for x11-xkb-utils, probably a dependency cycle.' Maybe is something I installed.

Comment: @Florin, if you'd like to ask a new question [please do so](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask?title=How+to+fix+this+dependency+cycle+error?&tags=apt+dependenies). You'll find it is a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5178/dependency-cycle-upgrading-to-10-04-lts), which already has [an upvoted answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5178/dependency-cycle-upgrading-to-10-04-lts/5179#5179). :)

Answer (score 3):

It will be changed in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to run the update manager as normal from the **System** -> **Admin** menu as normal, and you'll get an option at the top of the windows to upgrade your distro.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `lsb_release -a` in your terminal, you'll see that it says Ubuntu 10.10. Before there was also 'development brach' added.

Comment: You mean that you've done the upgrade with no problems and that in fact it upgraded to 10.10 final?

Comment: Note that it should be `lsb_release -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your actually suppose to run

```
update-manager -c
```